# how to get the difference between 2 objects fields in java

Tags: java, variables, object, methods, constructor

I have 2 objects in my java project and I want to take a field from each object(let's say for example we have 2 hotel rooms that among other fields they have also a field "price") and put em in a method and return a variable(in the previous example let's say the difference of those 2 rooms). My main question is after you create the method, how do you call it in the main class?
I did a try (code below) but I know it's not right.So if you could give me an advice on how to do it or approach it would be really helpful.

```
difference = priceDifference(roomA.price, roomB.price);
```

full code 
main class

```
   package project1;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRoom {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String roomNumber, category, view;
    int numberOfBeds;
    double price;
    double difference;
    Room roomA = new Room("C101",2,"Standard","Sea",95.89);



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give room number \n");
    roomNumber=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give number of beds \n");
    numberOfBeds=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give category \n");
    category=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give view \n");
    view=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give price \n");
    price=sc.nextDouble();

    Room roomB = new Room(roomNumber, numberOfBeds, category, view, price);
    System.out.println(roomA.toString());
    System.out.println(roomB.toString());

    difference = priceDifference(roomA.getprice(), roomB.getprice());


}

 }
```

class Room

```
  package project1;

 public class Room {

public String roomNumber;
public int numberOfBeds;
private String category;
private String view;
private double price;




    public Room(String roomNumber, int numberOfBeds, String category, String view, double price){
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    this.numberOfBeds = numberOfBeds;
    this.category = category;
    this.view = view;
    this.price = price;
}








public void setroomNumber(String roomnumber){
    this.roomNumber = roomnumber;
}
public String getroomNumber(){
    return this.roomNumber;
}

public void setnumberOfBeds(int numberofbeds){
    this.numberOfBeds = numberofbeds;
}
public int getnumberOfBeds(){
    return this.numberOfBeds;
}

public void setcategory(String category){
    this.category = category;
}
public String getcategory(){
    return this.category;
}

public void setview(String view){
    this.view = view;
}
public String getview(){
    return this.view;
}

public void setprice(double price){
    this.price = price;
}
public double getprice(){
    return this.price;
}


public double priceDifference(double double1 ,double double2){

    double difference = 0;
    difference = double1 - double2; 
    return difference;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Room number:" + this.roomNumber + ",\n "
            + "Number of beds:" + this.numberOfBeds + ",\n " + "Category:"
            + this.category + ",\n " + "View:" + this.view + ",\n " + "Price:" + this.price;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to **encapsulate** your fields.  Leave them private in the "Room" class, and use getter and setter methods instead of accessing the value directly.

```
difference = priceDifference(roomA.getPrice(), roomB.getPrice);
```

That's all the advice I can give without more context.  There's nothing wrong with this code.  If you're trying to debug an error, we'd need more information.

As your code stands, you should update the method invocation to refer to an instance of the room class.  You could change

```
difference = priceDifference(roomA.getprice(), roomB.getprice());
```

to

```
difference = roomB.priceDifference(roomA.getprice(), roomB.getprice());
```

Comment: well this is the priceDifference method(which is in the class "Room" that has the setters and getters of the constructor room) but I get the error "this method is undefined for the type TestRoom(main)

public double getpriceDifference(double double1 ,double double2){
  
  double difference = 0;
     difference = double1 - double2; 
  return difference;
 }

Comment: @sotosbic are you spelling the method the same way when you call it as when you define it?  In your code here you wrote "getpriceDifference(..." in your question your wrote just "priceDifference(..."

Comment: well in the instructions it said make a PUBLIC method double getpriceDifference(double1,double2) for the calculation of the difference between 2 prices. I thought that pricedifference is the name of the method and get is like a getter for this method (i'm beginner in java so i am not comfortable yet with java)

Comment: when you call a method you call it with the full method name.  So you could either call the method getPriceDifference(...  and code difference = getPriceDifference(...   **or** you could code difference = priceDifference(...    and call the method priceDifference(...  Does that help with your errors?

Comment: nop i still get the error The method priceDifference(double, double) is undefined for the type TestRoom

Comment: @sotosbic can you please edit your question to include the full code of both classes?

Comment: @sotosbic I edited my answer as well.  Take a look at the last line.  Try using that in your code and see if it works.  **difference = roomB.priceDifference(roomA.getprice(), roomB.getprice());**

Answer (score 1):

The proper Java way would be to add a simple function to your `Room` class

```
public double priceDifference(Room roomB) {
    return this.price - roomB.getPrice(); //or roomB.price if you do not use getters
}
```

You can then call it in your main application using:

```
double difference = roomA.priceDifference(roomB);
```

**Update: Solution for OPs problem according to his comment:**

I take it your method looks like this:

```
public double priceDifference(double roomAprice, double roomB.price) { // code here }
```

If that is the case, take it out of your `Room` class, instead put in into the same class your `public static void main()` is located in. Alternatively, you could access it without moving it using:

```
difference = roomA.priceDifference(roomA.price, roomB.price);
```

Please note that the first suggestion would probably still be the best option, as the suggestions in this update would be considered syntactically correct, but bad design. I just added the other two for completion's sake as per OP's comment.

Comment: Well this is a project for my university and in the instructions it said that we need to make a method pricedifference that takes the 2 prices at the same time. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Better than my answer, this is the way to actually do it.

Comment: thanks for your reply but in the instructions it says that the method needs to be in the Room class...

Comment: @sotosbic Then my suggestion #3 will do exactly what you need. Show some effort.

Comment: Your edit to your question almost made me erase my comment... but you still want to get rid of the dot in roomB.price.  I'm only being a stickler because I imagine your code being copy-pasted and then more errors...